# How is the Staverman's reflection coefficient in the Stirling equation determined?

Tags: physiology, kidney

The Stirling equation is expressed as follows

$J = Kf ([Pc-Pi] - σ [πc - πi])$

Here, capillary hydrostatic pressure (Pc) and Bowman's space oncotic pressure (πi) favor filtration into the tubule, and Bowman's space hydrostatic pressure (Pi) and capillary-oncotic pressure (πc) .

My questions:

- What does σ, or Staverman's reflection coefficient, in this equation mean?
- And by what logic or method is it determined?

References:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK500032/
- [https://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~petesmif/petesmif/why%20do%20we%20need%20kidneys/bowmans%20capsule.htm](https://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/%7Epetesmif/petesmif/why%20do%20we%20need%20kidneys/bowmans%20capsule.htm)